# How to .RequestFocus on last added EditView item in a cardview within a recylerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I have read numerous threads and documentation on my issue with different solutions and tried tons of them to no avail.

I have a cardview within a recyclerview.  The cardview contains an EditView and 1 Image.  Outside of the recyclerview I have an Add Players Button.

GOAL:  Click on ADD PLAYERS Button.  Add a cardview to the recyclerview that has the EditView and 1 Image and REQUEST FOCUS on the EDITVIEW of the newly added cardview in the recyclerview.

So far the code I have written works up until you add the 4th cardview.  Once you add the 4th cardview the FOCUS goes to CardView 1 and not the 4th.

Button Add Player Code

```
    btnAddPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


               RecyclerData mLog = new RecyclerData();
                mLog.setPlayerName(playerName);

                playerListArray.add(mLog);
                mRecyclerAdapter.notifyData(playerListArray);


//                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(playerListArray.size()-1);
//                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(playerListArray.size()-1);


            }
        });
    }
```

Adapter Code For Adding New Player CardView

```
public class PlayerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



        private final EditText playerNameEditText;
        private LinearLayout mainLayout;
        public ImageView deleteImage;
        public PlayerListAdapter(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            playerNameEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlayersName);
            //playerNameEditText.requestFocus(getAdapterPosition());
            playerNameEditText.requestFocus(mLastPosition);



            playerNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    playerListArray.get(getAdapterPosition()).setPlayerName(playerNameEditText.getText().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
```

As you can see in the above 2 code snippets I have tried other variations and none of them work.

Like I said my solution works but only for the first 3, after that it's no good and once you go past the 4th item then it is sporatic as to which one will actually get the focus.

COMPLETE ADAPTER CODE

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.PlayerListAdapter> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = Adapter.class.getSimpleName() ;
    private ArrayList<RecyclerData> playerListArray;
    int mLastPosition = 0;

    private RemoveClickListner mListner;



    public Adapter(ArrayList<RecyclerData> playerListArray, RemoveClickListner mListner) {
        this.playerListArray = playerListArray;
        this.mListner = mListner;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PlayerListAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item,
                    parent,
                false);

        PlayerListAdapter viewHolder = new PlayerListAdapter(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlayerListAdapter holder, int position) {

        Log.d("His problem here is:  ", playerListArray.size() + "");
        RecyclerData playerData = playerListArray.get(position);
        Log.d("Title is:  ", playerData.playerName + "");
        mLastPosition = position;

        holder.playerNameEditText.setText(playerData.playerName);
        holder.playerNameEditText.setHint("Player: " + (position + 1));
        holder.deleteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);





    }

    public void notifyData(ArrayList<RecyclerData> playerListArray) {

        this.playerListArray = playerListArray;
        Log.d("notifyData ", playerListArray.size() + "");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

          return(null != playerListArray?playerListArray.size():0);
        }

    public class PlayerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



        private final EditText playerNameEditText;
        private LinearLayout mainLayout;
        public ImageView deleteImage;
        public PlayerListAdapter(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            playerNameEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlayersName);
            //playerNameEditText.requestFocus(getAdapterPosition());
            //playerNameEditText.requestFocus(mLastPosition);



            playerNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    playerListArray.get(getAdapterPosition()).setPlayerName(playerNameEditText.getText().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });





            deleteImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteimage);


            deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mListner.OnRemoveClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

COMPLETE MAIN_ACTIVITY CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RemoveClickListner{

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Adapter mRecyclerAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    Button btnAddPlayer;
    ArrayList<RecyclerData> playerListArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String playerName = "";
    ImageView deleteImage;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerAdapter = new Adapter(playerListArray,this);



        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);



               if (mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 || mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() == NULL){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ZERO ITEMS LISTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        btnAddPlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddPlayer);

        btnAddPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


               RecyclerData mLog = new RecyclerData();
                mLog.setPlayerName(playerName);

                playerListArray.add(mLog);
                mRecyclerAdapter.notifyData(playerListArray);


//                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(playerListArray.size()-1);
//                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(playerListArray.size()-1);


            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void OnRemoveClick(int index) {
        playerListArray.remove(index);
        mRecyclerAdapter.notifyData(playerListArray);
    }


}
```

Comment: did you try to every time let the last edit text to get focus?

Comment: Not quite understanding the question?  When I run the app.  I click on add player, it creates cardview with editview and image and sets the focus to the edit view.  I type in a players name and then click on add player.  It works successfully for the 1st 3, when I click add player for the 4th time it does everything it is suppose to do except the focus goes to the first editview and not the newly created one.

Answer (score 1):

in **OnBindViewHolder** method of **RecyclerView.Adapter** , you should not immediately call the request focus , because what happens is by the time you call *requestFocus* on edittext , it woould have not finished drawing , so it ignores , so what you can do is you can post the code of requestFocus on the mainThread Handler like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlayerListAdapter holder, int position) {

    Log.d("His problem here is:  ", playerListArray.size() + "");
    RecyclerData playerData = playerListArray.get(position);
    Log.d("Title is:  ", playerData.playerName + "");
    mLastPosition = position;

    holder.playerNameEditText.setText(playerData.playerName);
    holder.playerNameEditText.setHint("Player: " + (position + 1));
    holder.deleteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);

    if(position == this.getItemCount() - 1) {
        holder.playerNameEditText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do check some condition for which item it has to be shown.
                playerNameEditText.requestFocus()
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: So I am not sure what you mean by main thread whether you mean main thread of the adapter or the main thread of Main_Activity.  I can't put it into main activity because playerNameEditText is not known, it is only known through the adapter.  So I added the code to the adapter and removed the other code for the focus and smoothscroll and I got the same results where the first 3 were ok and when you add the 4th the focus goes to the first one.

Comment: I just posted my full adapter and main_activity code.

Comment: Tried 2 other tricks.  In the xml for the cardview, I used android:focusedByDefault="true" and that did absolutely nothing.  Then I found another trick that I thought would work and that is to use an empty <requestFocus /> right after the EditView element and guess what it did the same thing all the other code I have tried is doing.  It will give the NEWLY CREATED EDITVIEWS the focus only for the 1st three after that when you do a 4th it gives focus to the 1st added item.

Comment: The code that you sent me works better than the code that I have, however the issue is now that it only works for up to 6 added items when I go to add the 7th it puts the focus back on the first one.  And I had to change the code to holder.playerNameEditText.requestfocus() for it to work in the RUN function.